# essential supremum of measurable space X

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$, $\quad$$\mu(X)<\infty$,$\quad$$f\in L^{\infty}(\mu)$, $\quad ||f||_{\infty}>0$, and
$$\alpha_n=\int_X|f|^nd\mu \quad where \quad n=1,2,3...$$
Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_{n}}=||f||_{\infty}}$$

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\epsilon>0$. Then there is a measurable subset $Y$ of $X$ such that
$$ \mu(Y)>0,\quad\hbox{and}\quad \forall x\in Y,~f(x)\geq(1-\epsilon)\Vert f\Vert_\infty$$
It follows that, for all $n\geq 1$
$$
\root{n}\of{\mu(Y)}(1-\epsilon)\Vert f\Vert_\infty\leq\root{n}\of{\alpha_n}\leq 
\root{n}\of{\mu(X)}\Vert f\Vert_\infty
$$
Taking limits we obtain
$$
(1-\epsilon)\Vert f\Vert_\infty\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\root{n}\of{\alpha_n}\leq 
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\root{n}\of{\alpha_n}\leq
 \Vert f\Vert_\infty.
$$
But $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\root{n}\of{\alpha_n}= \Vert f\Vert_\infty.
$$
Now, the multiplicative version of Cesàro's Lemma, allows us to conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{\alpha_{n+1}}= \Vert f\Vert_\infty.
$$